# Getting page speed insights for multiple urls

Tags: google-apps-script, pagespeed-insights

I use Google Sheets script editor to pull data via `Page Speed Insights API`.

I have already found an existing script and adapted it for my need. The code seems to be working for one URL, but couldn't figure out how to use it for multiple ones.

Here is my code:

```
var pageSpeedApiKey = 'API KEY';
var pageSpeedMonitorUrl = 'https://www.han.nl/ <<HERE ENTER MULTIPLE URLs>>';
    
function monitor() {
  var desktop = callPageSpeed('desktop', pageSpeedMonitorUrl);
  var mobile = callPageSpeed('mobile', pageSpeedMonitorUrl);  
  var desktopVitals = getVitals(desktop);
  var mobileVitals = getVitals(mobile);
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('results');
  var url = pageSpeedMonitorUrl;
  sheet.appendRow([
                       Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                       url,
                       desktop.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score * 100,
                       desktopVitals.lcp == -1 ? ' ' : desktopVitals.lcp,
                       desktopVitals.fid == -1 ? ' ' : desktopVitals.fid,
                       desktopVitals.cls == -1 ? ' ' : desktopVitals.cls,
                       mobile.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score * 100,
                       mobileVitals.lcp == -1 ? ' ' : mobileVitals.lcp,
                       mobileVitals.fid == -1 ? ' ' : mobileVitals.fid,
                       mobileVitals.cls == -1 ? ' ' : mobileVitals.cls
                      ]);
        
        // much more available, i.e. desktop.pageStats.numberResources
    }
    
function callPageSpeed(strategy, url) {
  var pageSpeedUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=' + url + '&key=' + pageSpeedApiKey + '&strategy=' + strategy;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(pageSpeedUrl);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  return JSON.parse(json);
}
    
 function getVitals(result) {
 var lcp;
 var fid;
 var cls;
   try {
     lcp = result.originLoadingExperience.metrics.LARGEST_CONTENTFUL_PAINT_MS.percentile / 1000;
   } catch {
     lcp = -1;
   }
    
   try {
     fid = result.originLoadingExperience.metrics.FIRST_INPUT_DELAY_MS.percentile / 1000;
   } catch {
     fid = -1;
   }
   try {
     cls = result.originLoadingExperience.metrics.CUMULATIVE_LAYOUT_SHIFT_SCORE.percentile;
   } catch {
       cls = -1;
   }
   return { "cls":cls, "fid":fid, "lcp":lcp  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use the multiple URLs for `pageSpeedMonitorUrl`.

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, I modified the function `monitor()`.

```js
function monitor() {
  var pageSpeedMonitorUrls = ['https://www.han.nl/','URL2','URL3',,,]; // Please set the URLs.

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'GMT', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
  var values = pageSpeedMonitorUrls.map(pageSpeedMonitorUrl => {
    var desktop = callPageSpeed('desktop', pageSpeedMonitorUrl);
    var mobile = callPageSpeed('mobile', pageSpeedMonitorUrl);
    var desktopVitals = getVitals(desktop);
    var mobileVitals = getVitals(mobile);
    return [
      date,
      pageSpeedMonitorUrl,
      desktop.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score * 100,
      desktopVitals.lcp == -1 ? ' ' : desktopVitals.lcp,
      desktopVitals.fid == -1 ? ' ' : desktopVitals.fid,
      desktopVitals.cls == -1 ? ' ' : desktopVitals.cls,
      mobile.lighthouseResult.categories.performance.score * 100,
      mobileVitals.lcp == -1 ? ' ' : mobileVitals.lcp,
      mobileVitals.fid == -1 ? ' ' : mobileVitals.fid,
      mobileVitals.cls == -1 ? ' ' : mobileVitals.cls
    ];
  });
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('results');
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)